# How to show content published from Tridion 2011 in separate .net application

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

We have a standalone .net application, this application is nothing to do with Tridion implementation.  But due to some strange suggestion from client we need to store some content (html fragment) in Tridion and publish it to broker, once this content is available in broker database we want to fetch it and show in .net application. Basically this content will a small block under right column e.g. like Login block (with user name password text box and some captions)

Is there any way to do it, also do we need to put storage config in .net applications config directory?
We are using Tridion 2011 SP1

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to spin up the Tridion Content Delivery Web Service, which is based on OData, point it to your Tridion Database, and then grab the content from there from your other website.

I've written [this article](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/deployer-and-odata-1.aspx) some time ago about how to get the web service up and running, it is focused on Java, but the steps are pretty similar for .NET. There is a prepackaged .NET web service you can just deploy on IIS, which then only needs the configuration part (cd_storage_conf.xml).

BTW - There is a Tridion-specific StackExchange site: http://tridion.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks Nuno, I will go through the article.  Next questions will be posted on http://tridion.stackexchange.com